# Adding object array to another object array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm re-submitting this question as I feel I was not clear on what I want to do with the code below.

I have the two arrays of objects, Users comes directly from my mongo database and before I send the result to the frontend, I would like to add the dummy data to the user object array. Now the Users list is a lot larger than my dummy data and thus I would like to loop through my user data and append the dummyData to every user object and once I reach the end of my dummyData, it should just start from the top again.

```
 const users = [
      { name: "John", lastName: "Henry" },
      { name: "Peter", lastName: "Pumpkin" },
      {name: "John", lastName: "Snow"},
      {name: "Jack", lastName" "Stevens"}

    ];
    const dummyData = [
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Agent)",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
        company: "Some Company"
      },
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(James Bond)",
        callStatus: "Pending Call",
        orderStatus: "No Order Placed",
        consultant: "Sally Sue",
        company: "Super Sonic & Co"
      },
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Peter Griffin))",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Jenny Oldstone",
        company: "Witcher School"
      }
    ];
```

The desired end result should be:

```
users[
       {name: "John", 
        lastName: "Henry",
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Agent)",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
        company: "Some Company" 
     }]
```

I think I can achieve this via a forloop, but I've never looped through objects before.

Comment: Just to see if I got it right, do you want to merge both arrays? or just add the dummyData array as a property on each user object?

Comment: Basically what I'm getting back from the Database is the users and I want to add the dummyData array to the users array, so when I access the data on the frontend I'll have access to all the properties from both the Database and the appended data from dummyData

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you want to merge both to send just one array to the frontend you can just use something like this:

```js
const users = [
  { name: "John", lastName: "Henry" },
  { name: "Peter", lastName: "Pumpkin" }
];
const dummyData = [
  {
    callTime: "Call Now",
    userType: "End User(Agent)",
    callStatus: "Called",
    orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
    consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
    company: "Some Company"
  },
  {
    callTime: "Call Now",
    userType: "End User(James Bond)",
    callStatus: "Pending Call",
    orderStatus: "No Order Placed",
    consultant: "Sally Sue",
    company: "Super Sonic & Co"
  },
  {
    callTime: "Call Now",
    userType: "End User(Peter Griffin))",
    callStatus: "Called",
    orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
    consultant: "Jenny Oldstone",
    company: "Witcher School"
  }
];

const mergedArrays = [...users, ...dummyData]

console.log(mergedArrays) // will return both arrays as one
```

I would not recommend that though as you will have to validate on the frontend the object type for each item in the array as they don't have the same properties.
you could just return one object with two properties like this:

```js
const users = [
  { name: "John", lastName: "Henry" },
  { name: "Peter", lastName: "Pumpkin" }
];
const dummyData = [
  {
    callTime: "Call Now",
    userType: "End User(Agent)",
    callStatus: "Called",
    orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
    consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
    company: "Some Company"
  },
  {
    callTime: "Call Now",
    userType: "End User(James Bond)",
    callStatus: "Pending Call",
    orderStatus: "No Order Placed",
    consultant: "Sally Sue",
    company: "Super Sonic & Co"
  },
  {
    callTime: "Call Now",
    userType: "End User(Peter Griffin))",
    callStatus: "Called",
    orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
    consultant: "Jenny Oldstone",
    company: "Witcher School"
  }
];

const res = {
    users,
    dummyData
}

console.log(res) // this way the response from node will be in two different properties
```